# React js calling static function into another static function on onclick event in html button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please find out following code:

```
var ResultComponent = React.createClass({

getInitialState: function () {
// … Some code …….

},

handleClick: function(event) { 
// … Some code …….
// Include html (displaying data)
this.constructor.searchResultMethod(para,para1,para2)

 },

statics: {
          deleteMethod: function(para = ''){
                 console.log(para);
          });
        searchResultMethod: function(){
        var html = ‘’
        loop{
                    var html += '<button id="button" onClick="'+ResultComponent.deleteMethod(1)+'"> delete </button>';
        }
        }

render: function() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button className={this.state.classes} id={this.state.execute} onClick={this.handleClick} >Execute</button>
            <button className={this.state.classes} id={this.state.save} onClick={this.handleClick}>Save</button>
          </div>
        );
    }

});
```

here i am redring execute and save . action define in handleClick , in this appending html with action, delete , calling deleteMethod function .

Here i am calling static function deleteMethod into another static function called searchResultMethod but onclick event get fire automatically  on loading of page instead of button click.
I am new for Reactjs. 
Need solution.

Comment: Try replacing `ResultComponent.deleteMethod(1)` with `() => { ResultComponent.deleteMethod(1) }`

Comment: Thanks Walk,
I have tried this :               var html = '<button id="button" onClick=" '+() => { ResultComponent.deleteMethod(1) }+'"> delete </button>';

But getting following error.
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

Comment: Actually, you're just calling your function and concatenating it's result with surrounding strings. Your syntax is weird to me, you're not using JSX?

Answer (score 0):

Try ResultComponent.deleteMethod(1) as static method needs to be access on class.